# Meteor Mongo shell not showing pubsub collection

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I have in server/server.js

```
Meteor.publish('accounts', function() {
  try {
    var self = this;
    var token = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId}).services.instagram.accessToken;
    var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token="
    + token;
    var response = HTTP.get(url);
    _.each(response.data.data, function(account) {
      var data = {
        username: account.username,
        full_name: account.full_name,
        profile_pic: account.profile_picture,
        category: null,
      }
      console.log(account.id);
      self.added('accounts', account.id, data);
    });

     self.ready();
   }
   catch (error) {
      Console.log(error);
   }
});
```

I have the Accounts collection defined in the lib directory, which makes it global. However, when I run 'meteor mongo' => 'use meteor' => 'show collections', the accounts collection is not displayed. This code is executed on the server, so shouldn't the data in the Accounts collection be on the server? 'use local' also doesn't display an accounts collection.

Comment: This code doesn't insert any data. I think the collection may not appear until you actually insert some data. "Accounts" has special meaning in Meteor, so it might be better to call your collection something else

Comment: @Mikkel Ah I misunderstood then. I thought publish inserts data into the specified collection. Where is the published data stored?

Comment: If you do `show collections` you will see a `users` collection but not `accounts`. You want `users`